# Match regex but only replace the first section - Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to take a phone number which can be in the format either +44 or +4 followed by any number of digits or hyphens, and replace the +44 or +4 with +44 or +4 followed by a space.

I believe I need a look around to match the full number but only replace the initial prefix, what I'm trying atm is

```
^[+]\d[0-9](?:([0-9]+))?
```

which matches the number (without hyphens) however I thought the lookahead would only match the number and not capture the extra digits however it seems to capture the whole thing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I've done wrong?

EDIT:
To be clearer my Java code is

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[+]\\d[0-9](?:([0-9]+))?");
if(pattern.matcher("+441234567890").matches())
                String  num = pattern.matcher(title).replaceFirst("$0 $1");
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have a solid premise or rules that an answer would require. That's why its not working for you.

Comment: You do not need to use `matches`, if `replaceFirst` fails to find a match, the initial string will be returned. You just need 1 regex for replacement: `String num = Pattern.compile("^([+]\\d\\d?)([\\d-]*)$").matcher(title).replaceFirst("$1 $2");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match whole number, but replace only part of it, you should not use positive lookahead, but just gruping, like in:

```
(^\+\d\d)([\d-]+)?
```

prefix will be in group 1, and the rest of number in group 2, so to add a space between these parts, just use something like group1 + space + group2.
In your example it should look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\+\\d\\d)([\\d-]+)?");
if(pattern.matcher("+441234567890").matches()) {
    num = pattern.matcher(title).replaceFirst("$1 $2");
}
```

However this regex will always capture two digits in prefix, if you want to match +44 or +4 you should use:

```
(^\+(44|4))([\d-]+)?
```

so if you have more possible prefixes, you need to change this regex also.

You regex didn't work as you expected because `(?:([0-9]+))?` is a non capturing group, so the fragment matched by this part of regex was not captured, but it was still matched by whole regex. So `$0` returned whole regex, and `$1` should not return anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However while that does match the prefix it doesn't match the whole number, therefore in java using that pattern.matcher("+441234567890").matches returns false.  I need to match the whole number but only capture the +44..  Or should I be using one regex to match and one regex to replace the prefix?

Comment: @crazyfool so you want to capture prefix and rest of number?

Comment: I want to match the whole number but only capture the prefix.  I've edited my initial question to show exactly what I'm trying to do, apologies if it isn't too clear.

Comment: Exactly what I was after.. Appreciate the explanation as well, thanks alot :)

Comment: @m.cekiera nice explanation. What's the reason for the '-' in the regex? Can you not do it with just: "^(\+\d\d)([\d]+)?" ?

Comment: @KumarM I add `-` because OP want to match _any number of digits or hyphens_  after prefix, not just numbers

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. Thank you.